# How to trigger a certain button using a custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting the variable through the url. http://mysite.com/?category_id=1
I want to trigger a button using a category-id attribute:
`<a class="cat-item" category-id="1" href="#">`

I don't have problems getting the parameter in the url. My only problem is how to trigger the button after loading the site.

thanks for the help.

Comment: And how does the parameter relate to the button?

Comment: you can also give an id to that anchor tag and then trigger it using id.

Comment: I dislike using invalid attributes like `category-id`, especially when valid ones like `data-id` exist and are even more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var catVal = getUrlVars()["category_id"];
    $('a[category-id="' + catVal +'"]').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the specific anchor tag by querying it by the attribute like below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $('a[category-id="' + your id from the url + '"]', '#categoryMenu');
    button.click(); //if your intention was to trigger the click event.
    button.trigger("some event name"); //if your intention was to trigger some other event.
});
```

As you can see I pass a second parameter to the jQuery selector. I do this to narrow the search to only the container with id 'categoryMenu' to prevent jQuery from searching the whole DOM. This will give you better performance on this selector.

So my advise is....

Put the buttons in a wrapping div so you can apply this technique

```
<div id="categoryMenu">
    <a class="cat-item" category-id="1" href="#">category 1</a>
    <a class="cat-item" category-id="2" href="#">category 2</a>
    <a class="cat-item" category-id="3" href="#">category 3</a>
    <a class="cat-item" category-id="4" href="#">category 4</a>
    <a class="cat-item" category-id="5" href="#">category 5</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks guys, found out my own way.

'$(document).ready(function(){  
 var queryString = getParameterByName('category_id');
 if( queryString != '' ){
   $('#course-category li .cat-item').each(function (i) {
   if($(this).attr('category-id') == queryString){
    $(this).trigger('click');
   }
      });

 }`

Comment: Arreane Diez Cayoca You solution is performance wise not the best. Try to use the attribute selector in combination with the second parameter to narrow the query selector. You wont need the each loop and my selector will be quicker.